# Фрагменты не заменяются друг другом

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть активити в котором один элемент - фрагмент. При нажатии на кнопку фрагмент не заменяется другим фрагментом.

Активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fragment"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login"
                    android:name="com.orekhov.oneclick.login.LoginFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Код фрагмента для перехода:

```
    Fragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вероятнее всего проблема у вас в этой строке:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment).commit();
```

Здесь `R.id.fragment` нужно использовать id контейнера в котором находятся фрагменты. Нужно добавить в макет контейнер:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

в вашем случае он уже есть, поэтому добавьте к нему id `android:id="@+id/container"`. Дальше используем ваш код, но устанавливаем id контейнера:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

[Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-replace.php) есть подробный туториал по вашему вопросу.

Comment: Раньше я так и делал, но считал данный вариант не совсем правильным. А для чего служит элемент <fragment/> ?

Comment: @Pempium4, чтобы не загромождать один макет кучей элементов их можно разместить в фрагментах и потом их подключить в один общий макет, таким образом будет проще работать с элементами по отдельности. Так же если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.